Tomcat catalina.policy file provides security policies to JVM in JDK 21 where Security Manager is deprecated
I have the following JAVA 21 code running within a Tomcat 9 Server where a method is invoked using a CompletableFuture:
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::makeHttpCall);

The method makeHttpCall makes an HTTP API call:
public static String makeHttpCall () {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://example.com/api/v1")
                .build();

        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            String body = "";
            if (response.body() != null) {
                body = response.body().string();
            }
            return body;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
}

A Permission Exception occurs when running the above task:
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "example.com" "resolve")
Similar exception is thrown when performing a task that reads OS details internally:
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "os.arch" "read")
I understand that the default security policy of the common ForkJoinPool is very conservative and runs tasks with no privileges.
Security Manager has been deprecated since JDK 17 and marked for removal. Tomcat still adds security policy via the catalina.policy file that is read by the JVM when the Tomcat server is started.
What should be the ideal policies in catalina.policy file to avoid these Permission Exceptions?

There appears to be no issue with: ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.arch")));. Details of JDK, and whether this occurs without dependency to non-JDK library would help. Perhaps you are running in a specific environment or container.

@DuncG I am running this using JDK 21 in a Tomcat 9 container

This question description is a bit misleading, its more about security restriction setup in your specific Tomcat container (needs more details) rather than general issue with ForkJoinPool.

@DuncG Figured out that the JVM reads security policies from the catalina.policy file when the Tomcat Server is being started.

In my own Tomcat (see a default download version, with no admins editing policies) the security policy for web applications has a grant {   section containing: permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.arch", "read";. Further down you'll see commented out section showing how to enable socket permission java.net.SocketPermission "dbhost.mycompany.com:5432", "connect";
